# How to build Android app after Buddybuild?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, buddy-build

Buddybuild team announced that they are now part of Xcode engineering team and Buddybuild won't be available for Android starting from March.

What should be my migration plan? Which CI/CD should I consider? Is Jenkins a good choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently wrote a blog about our migration from BuddyBuild into Jenkins http://badrit.com/blog/2018/0/8/deliver-android-apps-using-jenkins

Also, you can check [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) it is a popular tool to build and release your Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Our service https://www.bitrise.io (CTO here) should have the same features BuddyBuild has/had. If not built in then via an 3rd party integration (https://www.bitrise.io/integrations).

We recently published a blog post for those migrating from BuddyBuild: https://blog.bitrise.io

In general you just have to register the repository on https://www.bitrise.io and our service will figure out a suitable base configuration, similar to BuddyBuild, but then you can tweak this configuration any way you like.

If you have any questions I'm happy to answer, and in general I suggest you to check our docs (http://devcenter.bitrise.io), community site (https://discuss.bitrise.io) or contact our support via the onsite chat (available once you're signed in).

Happy Building! :)